# How to instruct Jackson to serialize a field inside an Object instead of the Object it self?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have an `Item` class. There's an `itemType` field inside of that class which is of type ItemType.

roughly, something like this.

```
class Item
{
   int id;
   ItemType itemType;
}

class ItemType
{
   String name;
   int somethingElse;
}
```

When I am serializing an object of type `Item` using Jackson `ObjectMapper`, it serializes the object `ItemType` as a sub-object. Which is expected, but not what I want.

```
{
  "id": 4,  
  "itemType": {
    "name": "Coupon",
    "somethingElse": 1
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is to show the `itemType`'s `name` field instead when serialized.

Something like below.

```
{
  "id": 4,  
  "itemType": "Coupon"
}
```

Is there anyway to instruct Jackson to do so?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to create and use a [custom serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

```
public class ItemTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ItemType> 
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(ItemType value, JsonGenerator jgen, 
                    SerializerProvider provider) 
                    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
    {
        jgen.writeString(value.name);
    }

}

@JsonSerialize(using = ItemTypeSerializer.class)
class ItemType
{
    String name;
    int somethingElse;
}
```

Comment: This works. And for sake of completeness, a related possibility is to make `ItemType` implement `JsonSerializable` (method "serialize()").

Comment: I don't know why I can't declare the Serializer as an inner Class, it keeps giving me an error.

Answer (score 37):

Check out `@JsonValue` annotation.

EDIT: like this:

```
class ItemType
{
  @JsonValue
  public String name;

  public int somethingElse;
}
```

Comment: Question was "How to instruct Jackson to serialize a field inside an Object instead of the Object it self?" and that is done by annotating said field with `@JsonValue`.

Comment: This is the best answer to the original question though pingw33n's answer actually helps my situation which was slightly different than the original question here

Comment: `@JsonValue` cannot be used to annotate a field (at least, not in version 2.6.7). It has `@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})`

Comment: It can be used to annotate a field in version 2.9 and up

Comment: For the super lazy (which is probably myself googling this SO answer in the future): Javadocs say _"Marker annotation that indicates that the value of annotated accessor (either field or "getter" method [a method with non-void return type, no args]) is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance"_ http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html

Answer (score 5):

As OP only wants to serialize one field, you could also use the `@JsonIdentityInfo` and `@JsonIdentityReference` annotations:

```
class Item {
    int id;
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="name")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    ItemType itemType;
}
```

For more info, see [How to serialize only the ID of a child with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542240/how-to-serialize-only-the-id-of-a-child-with-jackson).

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It's much simpler and solves the OP's problem more elegantly.

Comment: That's especially useful if the serialized class is not from your own codebase but from a library. Or if you simply you don't want to add JSON annotations to the serilaized class.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a quick workaround is to add an extra getter on `Item` to return `ItemType.name`, and mark `ItemType` getter with `@JsonIgnore`?

Answer (score 2):

To return simple string, you can use default ToStringSerializer without define any extra classes. But you have to define toString() method return this value only.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
class ItemType
{
   String name;
   int somethingElse;
   public String toString(){ return this.name;}
}
```