# JPA Bidirectional Onetomany json endless loop

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

the program under this particular environment：
     EJB3.0 +  JPA + jersey Web Service

First Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_by_test_yao")

public class StudentTest implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    private ClassTest classes;

    public StudentTest() {}
}
```

---

Second Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_by_test_yao")
public class ClassTest implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classes",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<StudentTest> students;

    public ClassTest() {}
}
```

---

When I get the ClassTest 's students list. 
Exception is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

If I change the fetch FetchType.LAZY the Exception is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
cn.gomro.mid.core.biz.goods.test.ClassTest.students, 
could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

How to resolve my problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542240/how-to-serialize-only-the-id-of-a-child-with-jackson
This may help. The best way avoid loop.

Comment: For anyone having this issue, best solution is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/6835976

Answer (score 5):

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;
```

it really worked.  I just tried that on Bi-Directional @ManyToOne mapping. It fixed

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add @JsonIgnore annotation to one of fields to avoid looping

Comment: @JsonIgnore is useless. still in Excepton at 'org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:167) Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)'

Comment: Hm, strange. It helped me when I had the same Exception

Answer (score 1):

For bidirectional relationships you can use these annotations:

[@JsonManagedReference](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) for the parent and [@JsonBackReference](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) for the child.

Also, this link might help:
[Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Comment: Actually I need to get List in ClassTest also get Entity in StudentTest.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I got that..
You want to be able to fetch a StudentTest from a ClassTest and a ClassTest from a StudentTest?

Comment: Using \@JsonManagedReference and \@JsonBackReference you should be able to reconstruct both directions of the relationship during de-serialization.
Of course in the JSON representation both sides of the relationship are not serialized, otherwise you would incur in the stack overflow since the entites would keep referencing each other.

Comment: @AlexanderH So I'm pretty sure what OP was trying to do is impossible _but_ what if I only wanted the `List<?>.length`? Perhaps it's possible to see how many relationships exist from the opposite side without causing an infinite recursion?

Comment: I would define a `@JsonProperty` on the `ClassTest` side.
Something like: `@JsonProperty public int classSize() {
       return classes.getStudents().size();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Snippet must help you.

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "columnName", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Class class;
```