# FetchType = Lazy and optional = false not working in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using many to one mapping in my account entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Contact Contact;
```

In my DAO I am retrieving the data:

```
entitymanager.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Account v").getResultList();
```

Though I am using `optional = fasle and fetchType = Lazy`. I see that it is running all queries and retrieving referenced table data.

I am using spring boot. Below is my Entitymanager configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {


  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;  


  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    /*dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));*/
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }


  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
        new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
   // additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
   // additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);
    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
  }
```

In application.properties

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
```

Comment: How do you have configured your persistence.xml?

Comment: I am using spring boot so have configured in the java configuration class.I have updated my question with the details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize only the ID of a child with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542240/how-to-serialize-only-the-id-of-a-child-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use **@JsonIgnore** where you have given relationship between two entities.

> @JsonIgnore : as Spring Data REST will ignore fields or getters that
>   are marked up with @JsonIgnore annotations.

Comment: I want to get the contact_id but I don't want to get entire contact entity.

Comment: @JsonManaged or something like that