# Exposing relationship ID as part of the JSON payload for GET, PUT and POST REST calls

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I'm relearning Java, Springboot in a personal project. I have an entity named `User`, which is managed via the autogenerated scaffolding from `jHipster`. I also have a `UserProfile` which is an entity that I created to hold extra data (since I didn't want to muck around with the `User` object. Now, when I expose REST endpoints for `UserProfile`, I want the GET calls to include the `user_id` as part of the JSON, and the PUT/POST calls to accept `user_id` for the `UserProfile`, do the association and only then persist. The ORM being used is Hibernate/JPA. What Jackson annotations should I use to make this happen?

My `User` object is:

```
public class User {
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserProfile userProfile;
}
```

and my `UserProfile` class is:

```
public class UserProfile {
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Linking the UserProfile to the base User object that is used for authentication")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    // Note: Not marking with 'NotNull' annotation since we will not want to update the User object when upserting the UerProfile
    @JoinColumn(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("userProfile")
    private User user;
}
```

My versions are:
spring_boot_version=2.0.8.RELEASE
hibernate_version=5.2.17.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got this working myself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542240/how-to-serialize-only-the-id-of-a-child-with-jackson/17583175#17583175) SO post helped me solve the issue. And here are my domain model classes with the annotations that worked:

```
public class User {
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserProfile userProfile;
}
public class UserProfile {
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Linking the UserProfile to the base User object that is used for authentication")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    // Note: Not marking with 'NotNull' annotation since we will not want to update the User object when upserting the UerProfile
    @JoinColumn(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"login", "password", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "activated", "langKey", "imageUrl", "resetDate"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
    private User user;
}
```